# How to get the full post content for certain articles only in the home page. <?php the_excerpt(); ?> vs <?php the_content(); ?>

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I was wondering if there was a way to choose whether a certain post can display the full content or just the excerpt on the home page in wordpress.  On my content.php I changed the php the_excerpt();  to php the_content(); but that displays all of my featured images AND the first pic of the gallery which is not what I want to happen, so i had to change it back. I do a link dump but would like the external links on home page for easier access. I have attached a link to show what I would like to display on the home page for that post and others like it. I have all linkdumps in a single category if that helps any.

http://badsentinel.com/2014/07/30/hot-links-around-the-net-124/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I was able to figure it out on my own. I ended up using an if statement.. `if (in_category('Links')) {'  'the_excerpt();'   '} else {'  'the_content();  }`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out on my own. I ended up using an if statement..

```
if (in_category('Links')) {
    the_excerpt();
  } else {
    the_content();
 }
```